# # getting month and day from date #

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in which there is a column, `ci_birthday`. The column is declared as `nvarchar(50)`, the format is `mm-dd-yyyy`. The data in the table is like this:

```
CI_BIRTHDAY
-----------

07/14/1956
NULL
NULL
11/01/1969
08/15/1955
07/08/1965
NULL
NULL
09/20/1936
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0/0/0
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0/0/0
NULL
NULL
1/29/1940
NULL
0/0/0
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
08/11/1949
```

I want the output from that column is only month and day, like

```
09/20
0/0 
1/29
08/11
0/0
```

Comment: How on earth is 0/0 a valid month/day?

Comment: If you used a date field you could use built in SQL Server MONTH() and DAY() functions?

Comment: Also you say it is mm-dd-yyyy then why is it 07/14/1956? And sometimes 0/0/0 and sometimes leading 0 is missing (e.g. 1/29/1940)? I strongly recommend you clean up this data and use the right data type. There is absolutely no reason you should be storing birthdays in nvarchar(50). None.

Comment: Store dates as dates. "07/14/1956" is not a date,l it's a string!

Comment: What is the purpose of **0/0** to represent the NULL values, why can you not filter these from the results?

Answer (score 0):

I accept my solution is a very bad way of solving this but if the date is not stored in a date format (in this case its a string), then you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(15) = '11/01/1969'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Date, 1,LEN(@Date) - PATINDEX('%/%',REVERSE(@Date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how to cast this very messy data into dates after checking it's safe to do so:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;

WITH    Dates
          AS ( SELECT   '07/14/1956' AS DateStr
               UNION
               SELECT   '11/01/1969'
               UNION
               SELECT   '08/15/1955'
               UNION
               SELECT   '07/08/1965'
               UNION
               SELECT   '09/20/1936'
               UNION
               SELECT   '0/0/0'
               UNION
               SELECT   NULL
               UNION
               SELECT   '1/29/1940'
             )
    SELECT  CASE WHEN ISDATE(DateStr) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(DATE, DateStr, 101), 101)
                 ELSE '00/00'
            END AS [DD/MM]
    FROM    Dates
```